# MySlq Select из многие ко многим

Tags: mysql, select, many-to-many

Есть таблицы пользователей и книг:

```
USERS:
- IdUser
- NameUser

BOOKS
- IdBook
- NameBook

UserBook
- IdUserBook
- IdUser
- IdBook
```

Необходимо вывести для пользователя все книги и напротив каждой сделать статус "прочитана", в случае, если в таблице UserBook есть запись IdUser:IdBook

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  b.NameBook
  IF(ub.IdUserBool IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS Reading
FROM
  books b
  LEFT JOIN UserBook ub ON (
    b.IdBook = ub.IdBook AND
    ub.IdUser = :user_id
  )
```